EF Core: How to scaffold and work with 2 schemas from Postgres with shared FK between them
I try for the first time to manage two schemas in Postgres where one id from the 1st schema is referenced as FK in the 2nd schema in another table. I tried scaffolding the schemas as separate contexts and separate folders for the entities, however the referenced table is duplicated in both schemas. How do you go about it?
